# How is the center of a data distribution defined exactly?

Tags: statistics

No, I am not talking about the *measure of the center* but the *center* of a distribution.  A thing and another that measures it are two different things.  So what exactly is the center of a distribution?  I tried to find an accurate definition in several textbooks but with no luck.

However, I did find a somewhat definition here: https://stattrek.com/statistics/charts/compare-data-sets.aspx

> **Center.**  Graphically, the center of a distribution is the point where about half of the observations are on either side.

However, would not this definition grant the median the always perfect measure of the center, even though it does not take into account all the data?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing formally called the *center of a distribution*. I assume that you are thinking about something like the central trend of a random variable, but you need to confirm. A possible answer is the *expectation*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking "What is the construct that measures of central tendency, such as the median, mean and mode, are actually measuring?"

This is would be the **central tendency** of a given data distribution, which is typically defined as **a data value that represents the central position or "typically value" of a data set.** The reason there are several measures is because no single measure is a great representation of the "typical value" for all distributions. So it's valuable to be familiar with all of them and the circumstances in which they provide useful information.

In my opinion, the definition you provided via the link is not a strict definition of the median because it is saying the center is a data point where "about" half of the observations are on either side; a median would be a data point under which exactly $50$% of the observations lie (with perhaps a negligible amount of wiggle room depending on the formula being used). It seems to me that they're trying to convey an intuitive sense for the central tendency of a distribution apart from the typical jargon that is used.

Answer (score 1):

For a symmetrical distributions, the center is the point about which the PDF (discrete or continuous) is symmetrical.

This point may not be the mean (the symmetrical Cauchy distribution has no mean). And this point may not be the mode: densities of beta distributions, with equal shape parameters both $\le 1,$ have their *minimum* at the center.

[image]

I'm not sure there is an obvious definition of 'center' for asymmetrical distributions. For various distributions points defined as mean, median, mode, or midrange (halfway between min and max, if they exist)
may be defined as the *location.* Sometimes
a family of distributions will have a [location parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_parameter) that has no direct relationship with mean, median, or mode.

Some 
nonparametric tests (for non-normal data) test to see if two samples came from population distributions with the
same "location." (Often the median is used as the location, but not always. "Central tendency" is not generally a part of that discussion.)

*Note:* You may want to look at Wikipedia 
 for uniform, exponential, gamma, Weibull, and Pareto distributions to see various discussions of location.)